# Calculate target quaternion without cheating with lookAt

Tags: three.js

How does one calculate the target quaternion (to be used later for slerp) for camera without stashing current quaternion and using lookAt?

This gives me the result (i.e. toQuaternion) I want:

```
// newTarget is Vector3
let fromQuaternion = (new THREE.Quaternion()).copy(this.camera.quaternion);
this.camera.lookAt(newTarget);
let toQuaternion = (new THREE.Quaternion()).copy(this.camera.quaternion);
this.camera.quaternion.set(fromQuaternion.x, fromQuaternion.y, fromQuaternion.z, fromQuaternion.w);
```

I'm trying to avoid the above with the following, but it's not working (getting much greater quaternion):

```
// currentTarget, newTarget are Vector3
var _c = (new THREE.Vector3()).copy(this.camera.position);
var _t0 = (new THREE.Vector3()).copy(currentTarget).sub(_c).normalize();
var _t1 = (new THREE.Vector3()).copy(newTarget).sub(_c).normalize();
var toQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
toQuaternion.setFromUnitVectors(_t1, _t0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the direction of the quaternion and initializing it to the current camera works:

```
    var _c = (new THREE.Vector3()).copy(this.camera.position);
    var _t0 = (new THREE.Vector3()).copy(currentTarget).sub(_c).normalize();
    var _t1 = (new THREE.Vector3()).copy(this.orbitControls.target).sub(_c).normalize();
    var toQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
    toQuaternion.setFromUnitVectors(_t0, _t1);
    toQuaternion.multiply(this.camera.quaternion);
```